# How to increment a generic type value in java

Tags: java, generics, data-structures

My task is to transform a given class into an abstract and generic class ,producing a sequence of values of generic type ,and supporting a single constructor that accepts an initial value .

Here is the given class:

```
public class Progression {

protected long current;

public Progression(){

    this.current=0;
}

public Progression(long start){
    this.current=start;
}
public long nextValue(){
    long answer= current;
    advance();
    return answer;
}
protected void advance(){
    current++;
}

public void printProgression(int n){
    System.out.println(nextValue());
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
        System.out.println(" "+nextValue());
    }
    System.out.println();
}
}
```

I made transform  like this:

```
abstract class ReProgression<T> {
protected T current;
public ReProgression(T start){
    current=start;
}
public T nextValue(){
    T answer= current;
    advance();
    return answer;
}
public void advance(){


}
public void printProgression(int n){
    System.out.println(nextValue());
    for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
        System.out.println(" "+nextValue());
    }
    System.out.println();
}

}
```

How can I increment the generic value "current" in advance() function?

Comment: That doesn't make any sense whatsoever. How would you "advance" a `string`? What is the next value of `SomeCustomType`? You'd need to _at least_ restrict `T` to be some "Incrementable" type.

Comment: Simple answer: You can't with how you currently defined the class. `T` could be anything. A `String`, an `Array` or just `Object`. There is no guarantee that whatever `T` is can even be incremented as it is not necessarily a number

Comment: I am thinking that too. What algorithm should I use then?

Comment: If you want `T` to be a number, you have to specify that, `T extends Number`

Comment: okay .I got it. Thank you

Comment: I would define an "Incrementable" interface and constraint the T to that

Comment: @Amongalen still it  makes error when i increment "current" value after make it <T extends Number>

Comment: How are you incrementing current? Are you still using ++?

Comment: @Kirit Yes. I am using current++;

Comment: Then what BigMike said is what what I would also recommend. Do you know how to do that? Also, your problem also seems strange. I also agree with Fildor, if you use generic type T, then anything can be passed in, and you need to be able to define what advancing T is.

Comment: @Kirit No ,I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @nooralight OK, I’ll write an answer to try and explain. But while I do that, please explain your problem a bit better. Where did you get this, what you are trying to solve?

Comment: @Kirit I got this problem from my book. My teacher asked to convert that class to abstract and generic type . I solved all the things but when I went for producing sequence , I am having trouble with this.

Comment: I am writing your answer, but it seems crazy that your book would have such a problem, iI am convinced that there is some extra detail you have not shared which will probably help us give you a direct answer.

Comment: @Kirit Thank you very much. But my teacher asked to make this transform. All he said is that, " Redesign the Progression class to be abstract and generic, producing a sequence of values of generic type T, and supporting a single constructor that accepts an initial value." That's all the information that I got. The given class, i provided it in this post

Comment: Go tell your teacher. Ask him if he even understands the difference between the primitive type long and reference types (generics only work for the later)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Possible solution 1

Progression is a term that needs to be defined.
In your initial example of `Progression`, you are advancing a `long`, therfore its easy to determine how to advance. Just increment the number.
When you convert this to a generic type from a long, you no longer have any idea what the type is (hence, generic) so you have to *somehow* define how to advance. The generic type T *has* to define the bavious when it 'advances'. The standard way of doing this in Java is to use an **interface**

I would create something like this -

```
public interface Advancable{
   public void advance();
}
```

In your `ReProgression` class, you would then use this interface like so -

```
abstract class ReProgression<T extends Advancable> {
   protected T current;
   public ReProgression(T start){
      current=start;
   }
   public T nextValue(){
      T answer= current;
      advance();
      return answer;
   }
   public void advance(){
      current.advance();
   }
   public void printProgression(int n){
      System.out.println(nextValue());
      for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
         System.out.println(" "+nextValue());
      }
      System.out.println();
   }
}
```

And this is the solution. I should however discuss how the code is called.
In the initial example `Progression`, you would call it like this for example -

```
Progression p  = new Progression(1);
p.printProgression(5);
```

Which would produce the output

```
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
```

To do the same with `ReProgression`, you would invoke it like this perhaps -

```
MyAdvancable<Long> startValue = new MyAdvancable<Long>(5);
ReProgression rp = new ReProgression(startValue);
rp.printProgression(5);
```

But you will also need to define MyAdvancable

### Possible solution 2

You almost have the correct answer yourself. You problem is to "transform a given class into an abstract and generic class". Declaring a class abstract only makes sense if there is at least one [abstract method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9556184/what-is-the-purpose-of-an-abstract-method). Ususally this is because the behaviour is not known or defined at the time of writing the code. This sounds very much like the unknown 'advancing' mechanism being commented on in your question. So what you have is almost what your solution is. Just remove the body of the advance() method -

```
abstract class ReProgression<T> {

   protected T current;

   public ReProgression(T start){
      current=start;
   }

   public T nextValue(){
      T answer= current;
      advance();
      return answer;
   }

   abstract void advance();

   public void printProgression(int n){
      System.out.println(nextValue());
      for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
         System.out.println(" "+nextValue());
      }
      System.out.println();
   }

}
```

The reason I have two solutions is because from your question, and without more background on what topics are being covered in the current chapter of your book, to me either of the two are possible, and you will need to decide which of these, if any, might be your solution. Good luck with your journey learning Java!

Comment: I see you have accepted Juliano's answer, which is cool. But the more I think about it, the more I realise that its possibly solution 2. If you are a beginer, learning Java, the more 'complete' solution seems too advanced a problem. Given you almost had the answer of solution 2, I am tempted to think this is what is expected from you. Maybe this is demonstarating your understanding of abstract classes, which is in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the great help. Your complete solution is enough for this problem. I didn't accept this much help from someone. This community is great. Yes , I am a beginner , learning java.

Comment: In the first solution, it needs to be `MyAdvancable<Long>` instead of `MyAdvancable<long>` - a boxed type. Otherwise, it won't compile. In the second solution, the abstract method needs to be specified with the `abstract` keyword.

Comment: @Amongalen Thank you very much. I have noted your corrections.

Comment: @Amongalen and i'll correct my code, I really ought to compile my one code before posting, but im far too lazy for that. Why didnt you just edit my post?

Comment: @Kirit I've compiled your code in my head. And I'm too lazy to edit your post ;)

Comment: @nooralight welcome to SO :) The big difference between your question and all the other I just move on from is that you took the effort to make an attempt yourself at solving it, and you showed this to us, as opposed to copy pasting your question and just asking for a solution.

Comment: @Kirit Thank you man. I appreciate your effort to help me.